# Segment Users by First 10 Days in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-filters

I'm trying to find out if I can create a segment of users who've been tracked for less than 10 days vs more than 10 days. Is this possible using Google Analytics segments?

E.g. It's an app that's being tracked. There's a 10 day demo and anyone using the app beyond this must have purchased the app. So, trying to get a separation of Demo and Purchased users.

Any insights on how to achieve this would be most welcome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an app, you should be able to build an audience using the **first_open** automatically tracked event. You can select a value for 'X days' inside the audience.
Another approach would be sending the data to BigQuery where you can do a lot more filtering.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve solution, you can store data on Bigquery/Bigtable with user registration date and move your data to a new table if use has purchased app subscription, if not then to another table which holds data for users who failed to purchase subscription.
You can also have all data on same table with additional filed (flag indicator) for users who purchased subscription.